# Display loader on load event and remove the loader when background image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs. 
**1** : where background image is loaded
**2** : where **loader gif** is loaded.

what I want is , when there is a `window.load()` event is called then **loader gif** should displayed , and when background image is fully loaded , then **loader gif** should be removed. that's what I want to achieve.

```js
$(window).load(function (){
    $('.background_image_div').load(function(){
      $('.gif_loader_image').hide();
    });
});

// this code is not working.
```

```css
.background_image_div{
        background: url(http://www.banneredge.com/images/portfolio.jpg);
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: thin black solid;
        z-index: 900;
    }

    .gif_loader_image{
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: url(https://media0.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/200_s.gif);
     //   border: thin red solid;
        left: 55%;
        bottom: 15%;
        z-index: 1001;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gif_loader_image"></div>
<div class="background_image_div">
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: use `setTimeout` function

Comment: i can't use. as there might be slow internet connection so if i put settimeout for  2 seconds then even if there is slow internet connection , then the loader will disappear without displaying image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `$(window).load(function (){` do a `$( document ).ready(function() {` as,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $('.background_image_div').load(function(){
     $('.gif_loader_image').hide();
  });
});
```

**EDIT** Caveats of the load event when used with images as taken from here, [.load API](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

**EDIT 2** try a poller, keep polling and check for the image inside the div using `.length > 0`. Do some changes to your html,

Keep a div and then an image tag inside it with this structure, `<div id="backgroundImageDiv"><img src="whatEverTheURLIs" id="backgroundImageID"></div>`

Inside your poller check if `$("#backgroundImageDiv > #backgroundImageID").length() > 0`

If the condition satisfies, hide the gif loader using `.hide()`. Check for the syntaxes please.

By poller I mean an interval timer.

Comment: tried, too.. not working... :( . does it work for you?

Comment: @Rishi try the poller method, has worked in the past for me for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as like this way.
Just see this link

```
<div class="feature"><div class="loader"><img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif"></div></div>


$(function(){
    var bgimage = new Image();      
    bgimage.src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-10.jpg";       

    $(bgimage).load(function(){
        $(".feature").css("background-image","url("+$(this).attr("src")+")").fadeIn(2000);   
            $(".loader").hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4d9xxon

Comment: not working.. and I don't want any time to be there. loader should be removed when the whole image is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.gif_loader_image').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

```css
body{
  background: url(http://www.banneredge.com/images/portfolio.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.gif_loader_image{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1001;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  text-align:center;
}
.gif_loader_image img{
  width:30px;
  margin-top:40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gif_loader_image">
  <img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/200_s.gif" alt="Loader..."/>
</div>
<div class="background_image_div"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want any time to be there. loader should be removed when the whole image is displayed.

Comment: I Just updated your code for an example. Try this code for large image, This will work for your whole page. @Rishi

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your `$(window).load` doesn't even fire

**Why**

This won't work since the [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method was fully removed by jQuery 3 and since you are working with the version `3.1.1` it's not a surprise that your code doesn't work. You have to use now the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to achieve the same effect

So

```
$(window).load(function (){
    $('.background_image_div').load(function(){
      $('.gif_loader_image').hide();
    });
});
```

would turn into

```
$(window).on('load', function (){
    $('.background_image_div').on('load', function(){
      $('.gif_loader_image').hide();
    });
});
```

**Notice**

Since you have already the `$(window).load` function at the beginning you don't have to define it again for your background image because this method will only be fired when all images are fully loaded so I think in your case this should also do the job.

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.gif_loader_image').hide();
});
```